# Why does my Perl if condition always evaluate to true?

Tags: perl, file, if-statement, file-read

In Perl, I need to read a .conf file that contains either a 0 or a 1. If the value is one, I need to execute whatever is in the if statement. Here is what I have now:

```
open(CONF, "/var/web/onhit.conf");
if(<CONF>) {
   print "Hello World!";
}
close(CONF);
```

The contents of the if statement always evaluate, even if the .conf file contains a 0. I know the file reading is correct because this code can read the file correctly:

```
open(CONF, "/var/web/onhit.conf");
print <CONF>;
close(CONF);
```

If the file contains a 1, it prints a 1, and vice versa. Does anyone know what is wrong with my first snippet? Sorry, but I am a n00b at Perl. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: Apparently, you had the truth value of your post inverted, and you meant to say that the if() statement *always* executed. This makes sense. What happens is that `<CONF>` reads in the string `"1\n"` or `"0\n"`, not the number `1` or `0`. The trailing newline prevents `"0"` from evaluating as false, so you need to `chomp()` it (or use the `int()` function, as mentioned in the other post). Either way should work.

(Note that, unfortunately, `chomp()` does *not* return the `chomp()`ed string, but a count of how many characters it removed, so you can't just say `if(chomp(my $tmp = <CONF>))` and be done with it.)

Anyway, this is what I did:

```
open(CONF, "/var/web/onhit.conf");
chomp(my $tmp = <CONF>);
if($tmp) {
  print "Hello, world!\n";
}
close CONF;
```

A few recommendations:

- Consider using the three-argument form of `open()`, or at least specifying `"<"` in front of the filename.
- Consider using a variable to hold a filehandle (`$conf`) rather than using the older, clumsier filehandle form (`CONF`).

This is the code I would have written:

```
open my $conf, "<", "/var/web/onhit.conf";
chomp(my $tmp = <$conf>);
if($tmp) {
  print "Hello, world!\n";
}
close $conf;
```

Comment: Note the use of chomp() to remove the newline. Without it you would always execute the true branch regardless of the value.

Comment: OK that works. Thanks. You forgot a parentheses on the first line though. And I actually said it wrong on my post. The if statement always evaluated. It's fixed now though.

Comment: "You forgot a parentheses on the first line though." Woops. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to convert the string to an integer using the int function.

```
open(CONF, "/var/web/onhit.conf");
if(int(<CONF>)) {
    print "Hello World!";
}
close(CONF);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just include in the newline in the comparison:

```
if (<CONF> =~ /^1$/) {
}
```

Comment: but what if they omitted the newline from the file?  :)